# Error in rendering jsp page using Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to render a jsp page from my controller but I find this strange thing happening. When I run the application, it displays the actual html code of the page instead of displaying the view. This is quite strange what could I be doing wrong. So,it basically the whole html code of the welcome page is being displayed when I run my application.

```java
    package com.example.DemoService;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import java.util.Map;

    @Controller
    public class HelloController {



        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", "Raaj");
            return "welcome";
        }
    }
```

Jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <html>
    <body>
    Hello ${message}
    </body>
    </html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DemoService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple things that you need to do:

1. add in your `application.properties` this (presuming you have your jsp in `src/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`)

   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
2. Try putting `tomcat-embed-jasper` with `<scope>compile</scope>`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

There seems to be a bug, at least in IntelliJ, if you run it with `<scope>provided</scope>` it will not recognize the jsps. If you run with maven (`mvn spring-boot:run`) it runs fine regardless of the `scope`